# Get brightness-level in regards to distance (python)

Tags: python

I need to get a value from 0 to 255 (brightness range) depending on 2 inputs: distance and maxDistance. `If distance == 0` the output should be 255 and `If distance == maxDistance` the output should be 0. How could I implement that? And I have to do this about 300000 times.

Comment: This is not a well formed question.  Does the brightness fall off linearly?   With the square of the distance?

Comment: based on your remark ChandRobbertson's answer see my answer now including multiprocessing and takes into account brightness value scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it linearly would be a `map_range` function, like so

```
def map_range(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2):
    return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1))
```

You can use this function by doing

```
distance = 5
max_distance = 10
brightness = map_range(distance, 0, max_distance, 255, 0)  # brightness = 127.5
```

It might look confusing, but line 3 is saying "take the value of `distance`, which goes between `0` and `max_distance`, and make it go between `255` and `0`". It will return 127.5 because 5 is half way between 0 and 10(`max_distance`), and 127.5 is halfway in between 255 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

As this appeared a question with two variables of which one is brightness level and 300.000 calculations needed to be done a multiprocessing pool is required.

An example is shown below using maxdistance is 10 and distance is random value between 0 and 10. Total distance calculations simulated is 2.000.000 in merely 0.5 seconds using a poolsize of 3.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randrange
import time

maxdist = 10  # user variable

# you can change the brightness scale here
def brightdistval(distance, maxdistance=maxdist, minbrightness=0, maxbrightness=255):  
     result     = -1
     brightness = len(range(minbrightness, maxbrightness))
     
     if 0 < distance:
          if distance == maxdistance:
               result = 0  # or use variable "minbrightness"
          else:
               result = ((distance/maxdistance) * brightness)
     else:
          result = maxbrightness
     
     return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
     
     calc_distances = 2000000  # test variable
     distances    = [randrange(maxdist) for i in range(calc_distances)]  # simulation for x total calculations
     
     results = []
     poolsize= 3  # set poolsize between 3 - 15 will show difference in elapsed time.
     
     p = Pool(poolsize)
     start_time = float(time.time())
     results = p.map(brightdistval, [i for i in distances])
     stop_time = float(time.time())
     elapsed = stop_time - start_time
     
     print(f'My brighness calculations for {calc_distances} queries is done in {elapsed} seconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the fact that the maximum distance corresponds to the minimum brightness value, you can't really use cross multiplication between them, but you can use a bit of interpolation after determining the range of brightness values:

```
import numpy as np

max_distance = 10

brightness = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
distance = np.linspace(0, max_distance, len(brightness))

def getBrightness(actual_distance):
    
    i = 0
    distance_list = []
    brightness_range = []
    while i < len(distance):
        
        if distance[i] < actual_distance and distance[i + 1] > actual_distance:
            
            brightness_range.append(brightness[i])
            brightness_range.append(brightness[i + 1])
            
            distance_list.append(distance[i])
            distance_list.append(distance[i + 1])
            
        i += 1
    
    brightness_value = np.interp(actual_distance, distance_list, brightness_range)
    
    return brightness_value

print(getBrightness(3))
```

The above requires you to specify a maximum distance to avoid an infinitely large distance, so at a distance of 3 (after specifying a max distance of 10), a brightness output of the following is obtained:

```
76.5
```

Comment: Cool, that answers my question. Because I have to do this about 300000 times, is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: If it answers your question then please accept it so that nobody else spends their time attempting to solve it. As for the speed issue, you can do it several ways. The first one that comes to mind is to decrease the lengths of the list by adjusting the ```arange()``` step (this will also decrease the accuracy). There might also be a better method out there (such as using percentage weightings), but I am not sure.

Comment: You could also group them based off of their distances, and if the distances are the same or within a certain range, you use a previously calculated value (rather than performing the calculations from scratch each time). Once again this would come at the cost of accuracy if you use a range.

Comment: I would also use enumerate in this case. This might make it slightly faster, but I don't have much experience with loop efficiency.